# Using flags in new-style (decorator-driven) QGIS Processing Algorithms

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-processing

In QGIS 3.6+, there are two different ways to construct a Processing Algorithm.

1. Defining a class inherited from `QgsProcessingAlgorithm`. In this case, I can define flags for an algorithm as follows:

   ```
   class ExampleProcessingAlgorithm(QgsProcessingAlgorithm):    
       ....    

       def flags(self):
           return super().flags() | QgsProcessingAlgorithm.FlagNoThreading
       ....
   ```
2. Using `@alg` decorator.

   ```
   @alg(name='algorithm_name', ...
   @alg.input(type=alg.SOURCE, ...
   @alg.output(type=alg.NUMBER, ...

   def algorithm_name(instance, parameters, context, feedback, inputs):
       """
       Description of the algorithm.
       """

       ...
   ```

In `@alg` decorator approach, how can I set flags? There is no explanation about this in [QGIS Processing Script Documentation](http://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing/scripts.html).

Comment: The `flags` is a method of `QgsProcessingAlgorithm`, maybe it must be defined in the `instance` argument of the `algorithm_name` function. Just create a custom `QgsProcessingAlgorithm` and overload `flags` method, instanciate it and pass it as argument (`instance`) in the new writing way.

Answer (score 1):

Did not fully investigate. So, my answer is more a clue than a definitive answer.

Reading at the source code, you need to set `kwargs` in `@alg.input` or `@alg.output` to set dict key `advanced` to `True` (source code https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/eef91768220367614908ad207f7bf7a3be851343/python/processing/algfactory.py#L199-L213) because `kwargs` are inherited from method `_create_param`

```
@alg.output(type=alg.NUMBER, name='NUMBEROFFEATURES',
            label='Number of features processed', {'advanced': True}
```

Flag configuration should go also in the kwargs e.g https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/blob/eef91768220367614908ad207f7bf7a3be851343/python/processing/algfactory.py#L212-L214